# DJANGO static url linked to wrong folder

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am building an app with Django but I got a problem.
I am using DEBUG= True
I created the folder run/static where all the static files are moved when I use the command collectstatic ( so this works well)

I have this in the settings

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'run', 'static')

Now, for testing the connection with the static folder, I tried to add a file in the path testapp/static/testapp/testfile.css

After running collect static, correctly, the file is moved to run/static/testapp/testfile.css

Perfect. The problem is that I discovered that when I run the server, the URL http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/testapp/testfile.css doesn't read the files in the correct folder (/run/static...) but it reads them from /testapp/static... indeed if I change the name of the file in the run folder to testfile1.css and try the URL http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/testapp/testfile1.css it doesn't find any file, but if I change the name of the file currently in /testapp/static/testapp/ to testfile2.css and then, without running collectstatic, try the URL http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/testapp/testfile2.css it works.
This means that static URL is "connected" to all the static folders of every app (like testapp/static/testapp/) instead of the static folder that I choose with STATIC_ROOT (run/static/testapp/).

IS it clear my problem?
What do you guys think the error can be?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is how Django is supposed to run. So there is actually no error.

When running your development server with DEBUG = True, Django serves static files from wherever the staticfile finders discover static files. By default the finders look for static subdirs in each installed app. You can specify further dirs using the STATICFILES_DIRS setting.

The STATIC_ROOT directory, into which the collectstatic command copies all discovered static files, is intended for production purposes. In production this mechanism is very convenient, because you have to configure your web server to serve static files (since it's not recommended to user the Django development server in production). You can just point the web server (e.g. Nginx) to the STATIC_ROOT file.

You can check out Django docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/). But admittedly the documentation on this topic is not always very clear.

Answer (score 0):

To make the static folder work on both remote Apache and local Django development servers so, that I can use a Git repo to sync, this works for me. **collectstatic** will just make copies of static files, it will mess up your Git repo.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static/')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"), '/var/www/mydjango/static/',]
```